# Can not add both Individual and Organisation to case

Tags: civicase, relationships

When a case is created one contact is added. But later, when I want to add another contact, sometimes that is not possible. I've figured out, I think, that if the first contact is of one type, Individual, say, and the other one is an Organization, that is not possible because the search dialouge limits to the previous type.

Furthermore, if I add one Individual and one Organization when I *create* the case, it seems to be no problem.

I wonder why? And I'm fairly sure that it has been possible since we have cases in our database that have this.

Or is there a way to do this anyway?

Comment: I wasn't even sure that you could add Orgs to a Case, so may be that has been an addition that hasn't been fully worked through. Is the problem either way round, eg you start with an Ind then add an Org, and also vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

I too had this problem. What worked for me is modifying the Contact Type A and Contact Type B to All Contacts in the Relationship section (administer---customise data and screens---relationship types) Remember to do it for any Case Related Roles e.g. the Case Manager. I was then able to select the organisation type. I have set it up so a User can submit the case as the Original Submitter but the case is assigned to the Organisation so multiple users can submit cases but they get organised to the Same Organisation which makes it easy to keep track. Hope this helps.